# What is this Red Flag?

Tags: super-mega-baseball-2

In Super Mega Baseball 2 I notice this red flag next to my portrait.  I have yet to play a game online, so what did I do to earn this red flag?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SuperMegaBaseball/comments/8ijcsg/i_have_a_red_flag_on_my_gamertag/):

> That means that you are the party leader of the given session.